# Why should one upgrade BIOS?

Tags: bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is firmware and what happens when I update it?](https://superuser.com/questions/132428/what-is-firmware-and-what-happens-when-i-update-it)

Why do people upgrade there BIOS?What additional facilities are provided?I want to upgrade my d845-gvsr so want to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An update to a BIOS could mean ***bugfixes, support for larger hard drives, newer processors and larger memory chips, etc***.

You should update your BIOS just in case you need these additional features or to fix current MOBO problems. If your not sure of how to do it *(and if you don't need the extra features)* you are better off using your current system.

Updating a BIOS is not a complicated process, but you should be sure of what you are doing. If you are keen on updating your BIOS, I suggest you research it well *(if the manufacturer provides a manual on how to do it, **READ IT** well)* and take the plunge when you are ready.

Comment: because if you get it wrong it is possible to brick the machine - no working BIOS means no booting, and more time reading about how to restore a faulty BIOS

Comment: I'd just like to add under bugfixes part that sometimes firmware for Intel processors is shipped in BIOS updates. How important new firmwares are I can't say, since Intel, as far as I know, does not make change logs publicly available. Microsoft also pushes them through windows update, but users of other operating systems will benefit from new firmware versions loaded by BIOS.