# Is BIOS update is required?

Tags: bios

I have read somewhere that after BIOS update,  many PCI support and dual boot settings can be opened. I have also read that  some PC not supported SSD due to old BIOS settings.

So my question is it necessary to update PC and laptop BIOS after some interval of time?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Why should one upgrade BIOS?](http://superuser.com/questions/200823/why-should-one-upgrade-bios)

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily required, or even good, to try to update a BIOS.  Sometimes the results are tremendously wonderful.  In some cases, a change might introduce new problems.  Many people suggest not trying to change a BIOS unless there is a reason to.  (For many systems, updating the BIOS is a bit risky, because repairing a failed update can be challenging.  For example, if your computer loses power during the actual write, then fixing that might not be a very simple process.)

As for whether updating the BIOS is actually a good idea for you, or not, that may depend on a variety of factors, like exactly which model of motherboard you are using, and what BIOS version you're currently using.  We're unlikely to be able to provide a specific strong recommendation without specific details like those.

Answer (score 0):

Required? Definitely not. Advised? That really is a matter of opinion.

Updating a bios is always something that, if it goes wrong, your motherboard is toast. It is relatively safe to do so nevertheless, but because things can go wrong badly, I always advise: If its not broken, don't fix it. As in: If everything you need works, keep it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Newer BIOS versions are mostly for fixing any errors and supporting newer CPU models. They usually don’t add any options or functionality. They may restore functionality that was broken.

So unless you gather from the changelog that you’re affected, you don’t need to update.

I don’t know of any cases where SSDs were not supported before a BIOS update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct answer.  There are two modes of thought:

1. If it aint broke, dont fix it.  If everything is working properly and you are not experiencing issues, dont update.  The problem with this, is that there may be some underlying issue or feature your might not see or have.
2. Always stay current.  The problem with this is that you might fix one issue or receive a new feature, but with new code, there can be new issues.

The best thing you can do is research the BIOS updates from your current BIOS manufacturer.  If they say updates are critical, you might want to consider them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is best NOT to update unless there is a new "option/compatibility" holding you back from using/doing something.

Every time you flash your BIOS, you risk "bricking" your computer. Or making a device none compatible or some other unknown oddities.

So, if that risk is worth the gain, then flash away.